# If and else statements in Django template

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates

I am doing an encyclopedia project and on the homepage there is a search field where the user can enter in the title of an entry to perform a search. If there is a complete match, then the entry page will load. If there is a partial match then it will lead to a search page that will list some entry suggestions with similar titles. If there is no match or the search was performed without a query, I want the search page to display a message telling the user no entries have been found. I have the first 2 conditions down and they are working fine but I am struggling with getting the page to display the error for no entries found.

views.py

```
def search(request):
value = request.GET.get('q','')
if(util.get_entry(value) is not None):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", kwargs={'entry': value }))

else:
    subStringEntries = []
    for entry in util.list_entries():
        if value.upper() in entry.upper():
            subStringEntries.append(entry)
           
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/search.html", {
            "entries": subStringEntries,
            "search": True,
            "value": value
})
```

search.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% if search %}
<h1>Searching for "{{ value }}"</h1>
<h2>Did you mean...</h2>
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


{% else %}
No search results for this query
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `{% empty %}`

```
{% for entry in entries %}
<li><a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
No entries found
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 18: 'empty', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: What version of Django are you using? This is the correct answer for current versions at least. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Comment: Forget versions - this was there way back in 1.x versions. If it's not working you have larger issues - it's a built in tag!